# What directory should I save iOS downloads in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, offline

I’m writing an iOS app that needs to download web pages, etc. What directory should I use for storing downloaded files on the phone? They shouldn’t be deleted very frequently, as offline access is the selling point for the app.

Comment: How frequently should they be deleted and would you like the user to be able to delete files on their own?

Comment: user should be able to delete them, so I think that rules of `Documents`, and they'de only be deleted if the user's core info changed (so a major thing for them to be deleted)

Answer (score 2):

From going off of [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), it looks like you should save them to `<Application_Home>/Library/Caches`. Note that this *can* be deleted to free up disk space, but will otherwise stick around.

Comment: That's the Mac OS X documentation. The question is about iOS.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: If offline access is the selling point of the app, you should definitely *not* store the downloads in `Caches`. You should instead store them either in `Documents` or `Application Support` and [set the "do not backup" flag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28) (if the files are big).

Comment: @wonderingtomato the first thing I see is "About the iOS File System" but I'll change it to what propstm linked.

Comment: @wonderingtomato: Actually, if you go to the link, you will see that it covers both, and actually covers iOS first.

Comment: Yeah, I think `Caches` is no good, I can;t afford for the System to delete this stuff

Answer (score 0):

Probably in `bundle/Documents` [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12).

You should probably check when to expire them, anyway.

Comment: There is no such thing as `bundle/Documents`. The app bundle and the `Documents` sandbox directory are two very different things.

Comment: Ops, you're right. I meant this one anyway: `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex: 0];`